# Is it possible to add to "admin sales order view" without editing/extending core phtml

Tags: php, magento

I have a plugin which seems to be introducing a new block into customer account section without editing the core .phtml file, however, when I try and change and use the same/similar code to introduce that same block in the admin system order_view page it doesn't do anything.

Frontend Config:

```
<sales_order_view>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="ordercomment/sales_order_view_ordercomment" name="cdr_ordercomment_info" after="sales.order.info" template="cdr/ordercomment/sales/order/view/ordercomment.phtml" />
    </reference>
</sales_order_view>
```

Frontend file being added: (just to show it's a simple file)

```
 <?php if($this->isActive()) : ?>
<div class="col1-set order-info-box">     
    <div class="col-1">         
        <div class="box">             
            <div class="box-title">                 
                <h2>Order Comment</h2>             
            </div>             
            <div class="box-content">                 
                 <?php echo $this->getOrderComment(); ?>         
           </div>         
       </div>     
</div>
```

What I'm using for the adminhtml config (app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/{file_name}.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>

<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
    <reference name="left">
       <block type="ordercomment/sales_order_view_ordercomment" name="cdr_ordercomment_info" after="-" template="cdr/ordercomment/sales/order/view/ordercomment.phtml" />
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

I feel I missing something quite simple but after diving through google for a few hours I've found I'm just chasing Red Herrings.

If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated!

FYI, I haven't added any additional blocks or controllers, for initial testing I was just trying to show the same file frontend in the admin system.

Comment: you have to add new tab in order view or display data in content area?

Comment: When you say tab do you mean the tabs that a present across the top e.g. dashboard, sales, catalog...?

Comment: no tabs means in order view please check http://awesomescreenshot.com/0ee2rnw596

Comment: If I added in a tab would that mean I would be able to insert a block in to the bottom of the main page or would it just be a page that the tab linked to?